# Did Gmail drag and drop attachments get dropped in new design?

Tags: gmail, drag-and-drop

I used to [add attachments in Gmail by dragging and dropping files directly from Explorer](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2010/04/drag-and-drop-attachments-onto-messages.html). It doesn't work any more. Was this feature dropped with the new design?

Comment: @myselfpoddar: I accept (*and* upvote) every answer that offers a decent solution to my question, like this one. I guess 4 out of 9 of my questions are just too darn difficult! One of them doesn't even have a response, yet...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like internet explorer is not a supported browser for the drag and drop now. I tried it on Chrome and it worked, where as it did not on Internet Explorer (see pic)

[image: working]

I would suggest switching to a new browser otherwise you will not be able to use this feature.

Comment: Oh weird, it's working, now... I  wonder if it's related to the "Chrome has stopped responding. Do you want to restart?" messages I have been getting. I restarted Chrome like that since the last time I tried.

Comment: @Leftium I just assumed you were using Internet Explorer as your browser since I knew that, that browser wasn't supported for drag and drop. My Chrome acts up a lot, and it's usually due to not clearing my history. I had 200mb worth of history. I had to manually delete my history it was so bad, that I couldn't even clear it. For some reason, at least for me it seems Chrome can not handle having a HUGE history. Glad to see it's working now.